# Are both the GPU and CUDNN required for Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, cudnn

Tensorflow can work on `CPU` without any `GPU` installed.

Does the following installation improve the performance of Tensorflow when training the following `keras` model on Ubuntu system?

```
1). No Nvidia GPU installed.
2). Install the Nvidia CUDNN library on Ubuntu system.
3). Intel CPU with MKLDNN enabled.
```

For this `keras` model:

https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/tutorials/mnist

```
def create_classical_model():
    # A simple model based off LeNet from https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, [3, 3], activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, [3, 3], activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    return model


model = create_classical_model()
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

I just installed the `CUDNN library` on Ubuntu with `Intel CPU` with `MKLDNN` enabled, does this `CUDNN library` make the Tensorflow work better for the above model?

Comment: CUDA toolkit is required if you want to utilize GPU for training / inference the model, which is normaly we expect. But if you don't have GPU or if you don't install CUDA toolkit (properly), the tensorflow will use CPU instead. So, GPU and CUDA is not required but desired in general.

Comment: Only install the CUDA toolkit library and without the real GPU, does it improve?

Comment: I don't think so. If you don't have physical GPU devices in your system, then installing CUDA toolkit won't do anything for CPU accelerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it would not have any effect.

**CUDA** is NVIDIA's API which allows you to call specific functions in order to directly use your NVIDIA GPU into optimizing computational tasks.

**cuDNN** *(CUDA Deep Neural Network)* is a library aimed at accelerating Neural Network specific operations.

In its process of speeding Neural Network operations, **cuDNN uses CUDA**. Thus, CUDA being dependent on an NVIDIA GPU and cuDNN relying on CUDA, we can conclude that cuDNN cannot apply its optimizations without a NVIDIA GPU.